# elif is giving me an 'Invalid Syntax' in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a measure converter. I worked with `if` and `elif` trough the whole code but now i just get `Invalid Syntax` from `elif`.

```
elif original_measure == "inches":
   if new_measure == "meters":
      print(number, "inches =", number * 0.0254, "meters"
   elif new_measure == "kilometers":
      print(number, "inches =", number * 2.54e-5, "kilometers")
   elif new_measure == "centimeters":
      print(number, "inches =", number * 2.54, "centimeters")
   elif new_measure == "miles":
      print(number, "inches =", number * 1.5783e-5, "miles")
   elif new_measure == "feet":
      print(number, "inches =", number * 0.0833333, "feet")
   elif new_measure == "yards":
      print(number, "inches =", number * 0.0277778, "yards")
   else:
      print("'", new_measure, "'", "is an unknown new measure")
```

The first `elif`, `elif new_measure == "kilometers":` is getting an Invalid Syntax.

Comment: Missing ')' on the previous line.

Comment: thrre lacks a parenthesis at the end of the first if

Comment: Thanks, that was it, dumb me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the closing `)` of your first `print`.

Comment: This should be a comment ;)

Comment: Thanks that was it

Comment: @LoicM ,it solves the problem...what is your point...?i think Flashbin should go ahead and accept it

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan Just 3 more minutes, then i can accept it

Comment: sure,if it solves your problem